# Sonar displays no issues

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, sonarqube

I have this weird situation while analyzing a java 1.7 project with SonarQube 4.2 through Jenkins plugin. Everything goes fine but sonar shows **no issues** after analysis.
If I run the same project analysis on local sonarqube, I get the issues.

I don't know where to look. Any ideas are welcome.

Analysis log below:

```
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:2.2:sonar (default-cli) @ ProjectName ---
[INFO] SonarQube version: 4.2

INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Work directory: /home/user/apps/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/ProjectName/target/sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 4.2

[INFO] [09:04:05.526] Load batch settings
[INFO] [09:04:05.900] User cache: /home/user/apps/jenkins/.sonar/cache
[INFO] [09:04:05.910] Install plugins
[INFO] [09:04:06.335] Install JDBC driver
[INFO] [09:04:06.351] Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8

[INFO] [09:04:09.686] Initializing Hibernate

[INFO] [09:04:15.289] Load project settings
[INFO] [09:04:15.480] Apply project exclusions

[INFO] [09:04:15.961] -------------  Scan ProjectName
[INFO] [09:04:15.972] Load module settings
[INFO] [09:04:16.623] Language is forced to java
[INFO] [09:04:16.646] Loading technical debt model...

[INFO] [09:04:18.183] Loading technical debt model done: 1538 ms
[INFO] [09:04:18.214] Configure Maven plugins
[INFO] [09:04:18.827] Compare to previous analysis (2014-05-23)

[INFO] [09:04:18.889] Compare over 30 days (2014-04-23, analysis of 2014-05-22 22:24:26.0)
[INFO] [09:04:19.348] Initializer FindbugsMavenInitializer...
[INFO] [09:04:19.362] Initializer FindbugsMavenInitializer done: 14 ms
[INFO] [09:04:19.362] Base dir: /home/user/apps/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/ProjectName
[INFO] [09:04:19.363] Working dir: /home/user/apps/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/ProjectName/target/sonar
[INFO] [09:04:19.363] Source dirs: /home/user/apps/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/ProjectName/src/main/java
[INFO] [09:04:19.363] Binary dirs: /home/user/apps/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/ProjectName/target/classes
[INFO] [09:04:19.364] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
[INFO] [09:04:19.364] Index files

[INFO] [09:04:22.665] 377 files indexed

[INFO] [09:04:42.007] Quality profile for java: Sonar way with Findbugs CompanyName

[INFO] [09:04:42.350] JaCoCo report not found.
[INFO] [09:04:42.351] JaCoCo IT report not found.
[INFO] [09:04:42.353] JaCoCo reports not found.
[INFO] [09:04:42.647] Sensor JavaSquidSensor...
[INFO] [09:04:42.917] Java Main Files AST scan...
[INFO] [09:04:42.928] 377 source files to be analyzed

[INFO] [09:04:52.932] 109/377 files analyzed, current is /home/user/apps/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/ProjectName/src/main/java/com/abc/Location.java

[INFO] [09:05:02.934] 257/377 files analyzed, current is /home/user/apps/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/ProjectName/src/main/java/com/abc/Product.java

[INFO] [09:05:12.934] 362/377 files analyzed, current is /home/user/apps/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/ProjectName/src/main/java/com/abc/Listener.java

[INFO] [09:05:13.834] 377/377 source files analyzed
[INFO] [09:05:14.138] Java Main Files AST scan done: 31221 ms
[INFO] [09:05:14.166] Java bytecode scan...

[WARN] [09:05:16.194] Class 'java/nio/file/Paths' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARN] [09:05:16.196] Class 'java/nio/file/Files' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARN] [09:05:16.455] Class 'java/nio/file/Paths' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARN] [09:05:16.456] Class 'java/nio/file/Files' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.

[WARN] [09:05:16.983] Class 'java/nio/file/Paths' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARN] [09:05:16.984] Class 'java/nio/file/Files' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARN] [09:05:17.058] Class 'java/nio/file/Paths' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARN] [09:05:17.059] Class 'java/nio/file/Files' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[INFO] [09:05:17.543] Java bytecode scan done: 3376 ms
[INFO] [09:05:17.543] Java Test Files AST scan...
[INFO] [09:05:17.543] 0 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] [09:05:17.544] Java Test Files AST scan done: 1 ms
[INFO] [09:05:17.551] 0/0 source files analyzed
[INFO] [09:05:17.680] Package design analysis...

[INFO] [09:05:20.190] Package design analysis done: 2510 ms

[INFO] [09:05:21.947] Sensor JavaSquidSensor done: 39300 ms
[INFO] [09:05:21.948] Sensor Quality gate loader...
[INFO] [09:05:21.948] Sensor Quality gate loader done: 0 ms
[INFO] [09:05:21.948] Sensor QProfileSensor...
[INFO] [09:05:21.967] Sensor QProfileSensor done: 19 ms
[INFO] [09:05:21.968] Sensor SurefireSensor...
[INFO] [09:05:21.970] parsing /home/user/apps/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/ProjectName/target/surefire-reports
[WARN] [09:05:21.970] Reports path not found: /home/user/apps/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/ProjectName/target/surefire-reports
[INFO] [09:05:21.971] Sensor SurefireSensor done: 3 ms
[INFO] [09:05:21.972] Sensor CpdSensor...
[INFO] [09:05:21.972] SonarEngine is used for java
[INFO] [09:05:22.016] Cross-project analysis disabled

[INFO] [09:05:28.600] Sensor CpdSensor done: 6628 ms
[INFO] [09:05:28.600] Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor...
[INFO] [09:05:28.620] Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor done: 20 ms
[INFO] [09:05:28.620] Sensor ProfileEventsSensor...
[INFO] [09:05:28.681] Sensor ProfileEventsSensor done: 61 ms
[INFO] [09:05:28.681] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor...
[INFO] [09:05:28.694] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor done: 13 ms
[INFO] [09:05:28.695] Sensor VersionEventsSensor...

[INFO] [09:05:28.775] Sensor VersionEventsSensor done: 80 ms
[INFO] [09:05:28.775] Sensor FileHashSensor...
[INFO] [09:05:28.809] Sensor FileHashSensor done: 34 ms
[INFO] [09:05:28.810] Sensor Maven dependencies...

[INFO] [09:05:34.026] Sensor Maven dependencies done: 5216 ms

[INFO] [09:05:36.228] Execute decorators...

[INFO] [09:05:50.435] Store results in database

[INFO] [09:05:51.731] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://www.CompanyName.ba/sonar/dashboard/index/com.abc:ProjectName
[INFO] [09:05:51.906] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.notification.SendIssueNotificationsPostJob
[INFO] [09:05:51.908] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.batch.IndexProjectPostJob
[INFO] [09:05:51.991] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.dbcleaner.ProjectPurgePostJob
[INFO] [09:05:52.013] -> Keep one snapshot per day between 2014-04-25 and 2014-05-22
[INFO] [09:05:52.015] -> Keep one snapshot per week between 2013-05-24 and 2014-04-25
[INFO] [09:05:52.016] -> Keep one snapshot per month between 2009-05-29 and 2013-05-24
[INFO] [09:05:52.016] -> Delete data prior to: 2009-05-29
[INFO] [09:05:52.030] -> Clean ProjectName [id=2862]
[INFO] [09:05:52.039] <- Clean snapshot 60195

[INFO] [09:05:53.274] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.AlertBreaker
[INFO] [09:05:53.275] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.ForbiddenConfigurationBreaker
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:54 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-05-23T09:05:53+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 29M/761M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sonar analysis completed: SUCCESS
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Can you post the logs of the analysis ?

Comment: Are your jenkins and sonar instances running on the same server ?

Comment: Yes, they are running on the same server

Comment: I have solved this problem in a way that I have done a clean install (not upgrade!) of sonarqube 4.3, on a fresh db. Now I get the issues.